# not able to update 12.10

Tags: upgrade, updates, software-recommendation

I am not able to update 12.10 which my pc is showing to update.

following errors are coming

[image]

Comment: end of life versions can't be updated. Please install a supported version if you want help from askubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind It seems he is trying to update from 12.04, which is still supported.

Comment: @QwertyChouskie the question asks about 12.10, and the screenshot mentions Quantal, which is 12.10.

Comment: @QwertyChouskie 12.10 isn't.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex The problem (which I have run into before) is that Update Manager is offering to update to 12.10, not 14.04.  Thus the question is on topic, as he is trying to upgrade from a supported release to a newer release, and Update Manager is just getting mixed up.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are trying to upgrade from 12.04 (which will be End-Of-Life soon) to a newer version.  First, **make a backup of any important files.**  Upgrades, while usually working just fine, rarely can leave you with a system that doesn't boot, so it is best to always be prepared for the worst (although personal files can usually be recovered with a LiveDVD in these situations).  Now run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will update your packages to their latest 12.04-based versions.  Next run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge && sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ { print $2 }')
```

This will remove old leftover packages and config files that could interfere with the upgrade.

Now try running Update Manager again and see if it offers an upgrade to 14.04.  If so, then just let it do the upgrade, and you should be done!  If not, go into "Software Sources", and under the "Updates" tab, change "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" to "For long-term support versions".  Try update manager again to see if it offers you 14.04.  If it still doesn't, open a Terminal and run:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -c
```

If it offers Ubuntu 14.04, then run:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If it still offers Ubuntu 12.10, well, enlist the help of the kid down the block that has nothing better to do than fix people's computers. :)